# Django Rest Framework - can't created object with existing FK reference

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a serializer class in DRF like so:

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    created_by = UserSerializer() # created_by is an FK to User model

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'created_by')
```

My views:

```
class ProjectList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = Project
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
    filter_fields = ('title',)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = ProjectSerializer(data={
            "id": 12, 
            "title": "FooBar's Project", 
            "created_by": {
                "id": 1, 
                "username": "foobar", 
                "first_name": "foo", 
                "last_name": "bar",
            },
        })

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    else:
        print serializer.errors
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

This works almost as expected except that DRF complains that:

```
{'created_by': [{'username': [u'User with this Username already exists.']}]}
```

What I want is that the Project is created with reference to an existing user. What am I doing wrong here?

Note: I am tracking trunk for DRF, not from the cheeseshop.

Comment: Confused why you're using pk=8 for the lookup but id=1 in the serializer...

Comment: Sorry - typo. I was testing some other behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to assign an existing user, not creating one, nested serializer is not the way. As you want to just add the relation to the user, you will need to take a look at relations.

The `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` is way to go and since this field is going to be writable you will also need to pass a `queryset` attribute.

```
created_by = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all())
```

See the documentation to check the additional options that can be passed to this field:

http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations#primarykeyrelatedfield

Then your example post could look like this:

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=8)
    serializer = ProjectSerializer(data={
        "id": 12, 
        "title": "FooBar's Project", 
        "created_by": user.pk,
    })
```

Comment: Hmmm. When I implement this I get the `NestedValidationError` of `AttributeError: can't set attribute`

Comment: Can you show us the updated source code please (with the model) ? Feel free to use some paste service .. https://dpaste.de/ for example.

Comment: Apologies - it did actually work like a charm. I had mistakenly applied it to the `UserSerializer` and not the `ProjectSerializer`. I will post my code as an Edit to the OP. Great advice, thanks very much!

Comment: Ah nice, glad it helped.

Comment: One bonus question - is there any way to still return the full created by data with the Project API? Having switched to the `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`, I now only return the user's `pk` in the `created_by` field. Ideally I would still like to return the `username`, `firstname` and `lastname` as strings in this field.

Comment: Yeah, you use the `depth` option on the serializer. http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#specifying-nested-serialization

Comment: Actually this had no effect. I believe this only applies to `RalatedField`.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

This is the working solution:

```
# serializers.py    

class ProjectSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    ...
    created_by = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=User.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'created_by')

# views.py

class ProjectList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = Project
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
    filter_fields = ('title',)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = ProjectSerializer(data={
            "title": request.DATA.get('title'),
            "created_by": request.user.pk,
        })
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
        else:
           return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```